# Shortcut to enable/disable data connection from home screen?

Tags: 8.0, 8.1, settings, nokia-lumia-1020, cellular-data

In WP7, I could pin my cellular connection setting as a tile, which was great as I often turn data on/off.

In WP8.1, I have to go settings->scroll to Mobile+SIM->tap->turn the slider on/off.

The shortcuts menu when you swipe down from the top of the phone lets me turn on/off WiFi, Bluetooth but not cellular data.

Is there a way I can make turning data on/off more efficient?

Comment: What's your OS version in Settings -> About? Mobile data on/off toggle was added to the action centre in version 8.10.14219.341, released in December 2014. If you're running an earlier version, check for updates.

Comment: 8.10.14226.359. And the options I have are WiFi, Blurtooth, Flight mode, Rotation Lock.

Comment: You can change what actions you want displayed, just go to settings -> notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customise which quick actions appear in the action centre.

Simply go to **Settings** → **notifications+actions**, tap on any of the quick actions there and choose a new one. Mobile data on/off is available since Windows Phone version 8.10.14219.341.

For more information, see the [Notifications and quick actions](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/notifications-and-quick-actions) how-to at WindowsPhone.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can install an app called 'Cellular Data'. Pins to the start screen and displays the status of the cellular connection (on/off):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/cellular-data/9wzdncrdtbmg